# Element type of SortedSet allows for calculation of the successor of a given value

Tags: java, subset, sortedset

From [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet-E-E-) documentation:

> several methods return subsets with restricted ranges. Such ranges
>   are half-open, that is, they include their low endpoint but not their
>   high endpoint (where applicable). If you need a closed range (which
>   includes both endpoints), and **the element type allows for calculation**
>   **of the successor of a given value**, merely request the subrange from
>   lowEndpoint to successor(highEndpoint).

Can you explain what means

> **the element type allows for calculation of the successor of a given**
>   **value**

What types allow for calculation of the successors in Java?

Comment: This question turned out to be more interesting than I'd thought. At first I thought the documentation covered it well enough (by giving an example) but the documentation doesn't really tell you what `successor` truly means. *Based on the sorting method, the successor is the value that would come directly after your given value, with nothing possibly between them.* This was definitely not clear from the documentation without more careful consideration...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the element type allows for calculation of the successor of a given value

### It all depends on the sorting method

It means that, for the sorting method on your elements, you can calculate what sorted value would come directly after your given value, with nothing possibly between them.

From the docs:

> For example, suppose that s is a sorted set of strings. The following
>   idiom obtains a view containing all of the strings in s from low to
>   high, inclusive: `SortedSet<String> sub = s.subSet(low, high+"\0");`

**For Strings:** *(natural sort)* `high + "\0"` is the successor to `high`

**For Integers:** *(natural sort)* `high + 1` is the successor to `high`. *But if your Integers were sorted from high to low, then the successor would be `high - 1`.*

---

*For some values computing the successor is slightly more complicated...*

**For Doubles:** *(natural sort)* `Math.nextAfter(high, Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY)` is the successor to `high` since `nextAfter` gets the adjacent value after `high` such that nothing could come between `high` and `nextAfter(high..)`. *Note that you might run into trouble with max/min values or neg/pos infinity values for doubles, so you would probably want to check `high` first*

With real world floating point numbers this would not work (unless you set some limit to the precision).
This only works here because in computers floating point numbers **always without exception** have limited precision and thus you can calculate the next possible value in that precision (which is what `nextAfter` does).

Comment: @xtractic Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Dron4K You're welcome. And thank you for your question, it turned out to be much more interesting than I'd originally thought. If this answers you question fully then please accept this as the answer. Thanks mate.

Comment: @xtractic Does it mean we always have to know an element value before a high endpoint if we want to use the successor? 
For example if we have 
SortedSet<Integer> sortedSet = new SortedSet<Integer>({1,2,3,5,6}), 
the correct successor for the high endpoint(high=5) is 2?
sortedSet.subSet(2, 5+2)

Comment: Yes, you need to (and would) know the high element that you want to include in your sub set, and to make `subSet` include that value you need to set the high endpoint as the successor of that high value: `subSet(lowIncluded, successor(highIncluded))`. Since `subSet()` does not include the passed in highvalue, you need to use the successor of the high value for the high value to actually be included. For a naturally sorted list of integers, if you want the range from 1-inclusive to 5-inclusive then you would use, `subSet(1, successor(5))` where `successor(5) == 5 + 1 == 6`.

Comment: In a naturally sorted list of Integers, the successor to `5` is `5+1 == 6` not `5+2 == 7` since if you used `7` as the exclusive high endpoint then `6` would be included in your `subSet` when you really only want up to `5`. In a high to low sorted list of Integers, the successor to `5` would be `5 - 1` since `4` would come immediately after `5` in a high-to-low sort.

Answer (score 2):

Allowing calculation of successors require your type to have discrete values (although that is not sufficient).

`Integer` is a good example of this - the successor of `2` is `3`. The successor of `3` is `4`.

Comment: Actually, Doubles are discrete (when they have limited precision as they do in computers) and thus do have a clear successor. Also it should be mentioned that a "successor" is defined by the sorting method. If I sorted my integers from high to low, then the successor of `3` would be `2`

Comment: @xtratic yeah, I just "clicked" about `double`s, and edited this out of my answer.

Comment: thanks for correcting, though I still think it's important to mention that it depends on the sorting method. I'll also try to make that more clear in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For example, the whole set contains `1, 3`, and you want to get Integer from between [1, 3], if you directly call

```
s.subSet(1, 3);
```

then 3 will not be in the subset.

In this situation, you can **calculate the next element after 3** by `3 + 1 = 4` and call:

```
s.subSet(1, 4);
```

then 3 will be in the subset.

The calculation mechanism might differes from class to class. With `Numberic` elements or `String`, you can calculate the successor by `+` directly. If you are manipulating on other type, you can custom your own **calculation** method, and it should be consistent with compare method.